# WPF NotifyIcon. Как привязать метод к LeftClickCommand

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите, как привязать в TaskbarIcon метод из MainWindow (а не из отдельного класса команд). Пример от разработчика показывает как привязать из отдельного класса.

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon Visibility="Visible"
                    ToolTipText="{x:Static loc:Resources.MainWindowTitle}" 
                    IconSource="Images/logo_tfortis.ico"
                    LeftClickCommand="..."/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ, делает то что мне нужно

```
TrayLeftMouseUp="TaskbarIcon_TrayLeftMouseUp"

<tb:TaskbarIcon Visibility="Visible"
                    ToolTipText="{x:Static loc:Resources.MainWindowTitle}" 
                    IconSource="Images/logo_tfortis.ico"
                    TrayLeftMouseUp="TaskbarIcon_TrayLeftMouseUp"/>
```